# Listview in fragment not displaying all entries

Tags: android, listview

I have two fragments, one for portrait and one for landscape. When the app is portrait the `ListView` populates with everything from the server as expected, however when I turn the phone landscape the `ListView` populates, but not with  everything from the server (it seems to be missing the last 5 or 6 entries every time). I have debugged the code and can see that everything is actually in my message being returned from my server.

My code is as follows:

```
public final Handler myCallBack = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
try {
  lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  if (msg.obj == "No Response") {
     TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     tv2.setText("No Response. Please check your internet connection");
     tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else {
   dataList = (ArrayList<Beer>) msg.obj;
   lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   ArrayAdapter<Beer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Beer>(
   getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, (List<Beer>) msg.obj);
   lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 }
}catch (Exception ex) {
}
}
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely to be the way you pass your data to your handler :

Extracted `dataList` is merely a reference to the `ArrayList<Beer>` which can still change.

What you need is to pass a `copy` of you array data with the message, for this you need your `Beer` implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Then put your `ArrayList<Beer>` to Bundle with [putParcelableArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) and set Bundle to the Message before you send to to your handler's UI thread :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("myBeers", dataList/*your ArrayList*/);
msg.setData(bundle);
```

and later extract it in your handler with

```
ArrayList<Beer> dataList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("myBeers");
```

I am sure that will resolve your problem. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: thanks for the help just getting stuck on the bit in my handler, ive returned the message to the handler as a message and then im stuck as I dont have a clue as to how to get the message into a  bundle so i can use the getParcelableArrayList method. Cheers

Comment: Ok. let me summarize what you need to do. It is not that complex : 1. make `Beer implements Parcelable`. It is simple, see example in the link of `parcelable` or search for plenty examples on SO 2. You have to put your array using `putParcelableArrayList` into `new Bundle()` and then set this bundle to the message you want to send. Can you do that ?